# Keeping State in a Purely Functional Language

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, clojure

I am trying to figure out how to do the following, assume that your are working on a controller for a DC motor you want to keep it spinning at a certain speed set by the user,

```
(def set-point (ref {:sp 90}))

(while true
  (let [curr (read-speed)]
    (controller @set-point curr)))
```

Now that set-point can change any time via a web a application, I can't think of a way to do this without using ref, so my question is how functional languages deal with this sort of thing? (even though the example is in clojure I am interested in the general idea.)

Answer (score 15):

This will not answer your question but I want to show how these things are done in Clojure. It might help someone reading this later so they don't think they have to read up on monads, reactive programming or other "complicated" subjects to use Clojure.

Clojure is not a **purely** functional language and in this case it might be a good idea to leave the pure functions aside for a moment and model [the inherent state of the system with identities](http://clojure.org/state).

In Clojure, you would probably use one of the reference types. There are several to choose from and knowing which one to use might be difficult. The good news is they all support the *unified update model* so changing the reference type later should be pretty straight forward.

I've chosen an [`atom`](http://clojure.org/atoms) but depending on your requirements it might be more appropriate to use a [`ref`](http://clojure.org/refs) or an [`agent`](http://clojure.org/agents).

The motor is an identity in your program. It is a "label" for some *thing* that has different values at different times and these values are related to each other (i.e., the speed of the motor). I have put a `:validator` on the atom to ensure that the speed never drops below zero.

```
(def motor (atom {:speed 0} :validator (comp not neg? :speed)))

(defn add-speed [n]
  (swap! motor update-in [:speed] + n))

(defn set-speed [n]
  (swap! motor update-in [:speed] (constantly n)))

> (add-speed 10)
> (add-speed -8)
> (add-speed -4) ;; This will not change the state of motor
                 ;; since the speed would drop below zero and
                 ;; the validator does not allow that!
> (:speed @motor)
2
> (set-speed 12)
> (:speed @motor)
12
```

If you want to change the semantics of the motor identity you have at least two other reference types to choose from.

- If you want to change the speed of the motor asynchronously you would use an agent. Then you need to change `swap!` with `send`. This would be useful if, for example, the clients adjusting the motor speed are different from the clients using the motor speed, so that it's fine for the speed to be changed "eventually".
- Another option is to use a `ref` which would be appropriate if the motor need to coordinate with other identities in your system. If you choose this reference type you change `swap!` with `alter`. In addition, all state changes are run in a transaction with `dosync` to ensure that all identities in the transaction are updated atomically.

Monads are not needed to model identities and state in Clojure!

Comment: Please edit this answer if you find errors. The last thing I want is to spread misinformation about this subject matter.

Answer (score 8):

For this answer, I'm going to interpret "a purely functional language" as meaning "an ML-style language that excludes side effects" which I will interpret in turn as meaning "Haskell" which I'll interpret as meaning "GHC". None of these are strictly true, but given that you're contrasting this with a Lisp derivative and that GHC is rather prominent, I'm guessing this will still get at the heart of your question.

As always, the answer in Haskell is a bit of sleight-of-hand where access to mutable data (or anything with side effects) is structured in such a way that the type system guarantees that it will "look" pure from the inside, while producing a final program that has side effects where expected. The usual business with monads is a large part of this, but the details don't really matter and mostly distract from the issue. In practice, it just means you have to be explicit about where side effects can occur and in what order, and you're not allowed to "cheat".

Mutability primitives are generally provided by the language runtime, and accessed through functions that produce values in some monad also provided by the runtime (often `IO`, sometimes more specialized ones). First, let's take a look at the Clojure example you provided: it uses `ref`, which is described in [the documentation here](http://clojure.org/refs):

> While Vars ensure safe use of mutable storage locations via thread isolation, transactional references (Refs) ensure safe shared use of mutable storage locations via a software transactional memory (STM) system. Refs are bound to a single storage location for their lifetime, and only allow mutation of that location to occur within a transaction.

Amusingly, that whole paragraph translates pretty directly to GHC Haskell. I'm guessing that "Vars" are equivalent to [Haskell's `MVar`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.1.0/doc/html/Control-Concurrent-MVar.html), while "Refs" are almost certainly equivalent to [`TVar` as found in the `stm` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/stm/2.2.0.1/doc/html/Control-Concurrent-STM-TVar.html).

So to translate the example to Haskell, we'll need a function that creates the `TVar`:

```
setPoint :: STM (TVar Int)
setPoint = newTVar 90
```

...and we can use it in code like this:

```
updateLoop :: IO ()
updateLoop = do tvSetPoint <- atomically setPoint
                sequence_ . repeat $ update tvSetPoint
  where update tv = do curSpeed <- readSpeed
                       curSet   <- atomically $ readTVar tv
                       controller curSet curSpeed
```

In actual use my code would be far more terse than that, but I've left things more verbose here in hopes of being less cryptic.

I suppose one could object that this code isn't pure and is using mutable state, but... so what? At some point a program is going to run and we'd like it to do input and output. The important thing is that we retain all the *benefits* of code being pure, even when using it to write code with mutable state. For instance, I've implemented an infinite loop of side effects using the `repeat` function; but `repeat` is still pure and behaves reliably and nothing I can do with it will change that.

Answer (score 3):

A technique to tackle problems that apparently *scream* for mutability (like GUI or web applications) in a functional way is [Functional Reactive Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_reactive_programming).

Comment: Disclaimer: FRP is cool but I don't think it's really "there yet". It's great to read up on and I expect it to be a Big Thing in a few years, but in the short term it's probably more effective to look elsewhere and I'm not sure if it's where I'd point a newcomer.

Comment: Depends on what the newcomer is interested in, I think.  FRP enlightened me about pure functional *modeling* -- the idea that just because the only way I can imagine it working is by side effects / impurity, that doesn't mean it has to have side effects.  FRP *specifically*, however, has been quite a challenge to implement.  So it depends on whether the question is practical or philosophical.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern you need for this is called Monads. If you really want to get into functional programming you should try to understand what monads are used for and what they can do. As a starting point I would suggest [this link](http://www.tcrueger.de/doku.php/science/papers/dyn_prog).

As a short informal explanation for monads:

Monads can be seen as data + context that is passed around in your program. This is the "space suit" often used in explanations. You pass data and context around together and insert any operation into this Monad. There is usually no way to get the data back once it is inserted into the context, you just can go the other way round inserting operations, so that they handle data combined with context. This way it almost seems as if you get the data out, but if you look closely you never do.

Depending on your application the context can be almost anything. A datastructure that combines multiple entities, exceptions, optionals, or the real world (i/o-monads). In the paper linked above the context will be execution states of an algorithm, so this is quite similar to the things you have in mind.

Comment: Just for the record, monads are just one of several ways in which state can be represented in FP languages.

Comment: @jalf, what are some other ways?

Comment: And also, state or I/O are just few of the many-many monads out there.

Answer (score 2):

In Erlang you could use a process to hold the value.  Something like this:

```
holdVar(SomeVar) ->
  receive %% wait for message
    {From, get} ->             %% if you receive a get
      From ! {value, SomeVar}, %% respond with SomeVar
      holdVar(SomeVar);        %% recursively call holdVar
                               %% to start listening again

    {From, {set, SomeNewVar}} -> %% if you receive a set
      From ! {ok},               %% respond with ok
      holdVar(SomeNewVar);       %% recursively call holdVar with
                                 %% the SomeNewVar that you received 
                                 %% in the message
  end.
```